# Maximum value of $a+b$ given that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{20}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality, optimization, contest-math

What is the maximum value of $a+b$ given that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{20}$ here $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$?

> **What I have gotten so far:**
>
> From the above, $\frac{a+b}{ab} = \frac{1}{20} \implies 20(a+b) = ab $
>
> I noticed that $(a-1)(b-1) = ab - a-b+1 = k > 0$ when $a,b > 1$, because when $a, b = 1$ is clearly not a solution. $$\therefore 20(a+b) = ab = a+b - 1 + k > 0 \implies 19(a+b) = (a-1)(b-1) - 1 $$
>
> Using AM-GM I got that $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} \implies ab = 2(a+b) \geq 40\sqrt{ab} \implies \sqrt{ab} \geq 40 \implies ab \geq 1600$.
>
> When $ab = 1600$, one obvious answer is $a=b=40$.

Here, I am stuck... How do I find the maximum value of $a+b$ or perhaps prove that maximum occurs when $a=b=40$?

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathbb{Z}^+$? Isn't it equal to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Some people include 0 to $/mathbb N$ while others do not. Imo $/mathbb Z+$ is more clear.

Comment: If using AM-GM, equality happens only when $a=b$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{(20)(21)}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I posted that just before your comment, only to see that alex.jordan had already posted it. When it rains...

Comment: I was recalling rather than discovering, it is the simplest result in the theory of Egyptian fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a much more convenient condition by using $(a-r)(b-r)=ab-ar-br+r^2$ for a value of $r$ other than $1$.

> Notice that from $20(a+b)=ab$ you can derive $ab-20a-20b=0$ and if you choose $r=20$ you should see $(a-20)(b-20)=400$. You should now find it easy to finish.

Answer (score 1):

$a=b=40$ is clearly a solution. If one number is larger than $40$, the other must be less than $40$. But also neither number can be smaller than $21$. So one approach would be to let $a$ range from $21$ to $39$ and see what $b$ arise for each $a$ and if they are integers. And then take note of any values of $a+b$ and see if they beat $40+40$.

Actually right away you find that $a=21$ gives $b=420$. And if we drop the integer condition and apply calculus to the problem, we see that $a+b\to\infty$ as $a\to0$ from $a=40$. So this establishes that $21+420$ is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

From $20(a+b) = ab$, we have $b = \frac{20a}{a-20}$. This is an integer, so $a - 20 \mid 20a$.

Let $g = \gcd(a, 20)$. Then $a = ga'$ and $a' - \frac{20}{g} \mid 20a'$. But $\gcd(a'-\frac{20}{g}, 20a') = 1$ (since if not we have a contradiction with $g$ being the *greatest* divisor of $a$ and $20$), so we must have $a'-\frac{20}{g} = 1$.

Rearranging and substituting back in, $a = 20+g$ and $b=\frac{20(20+g)}{g} = \frac{400}{g} + 20$.

Therefore the problem is to select which of the divisors of $20$, that is $\{1,2,4,5,10,20\}$, maximises $40 + g + \frac{400}{g}$.